# Where clause on non-clustered index Vs extra join and where clause on clustered index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, indexing, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

I am trying to eak out a bit extra performance from some sql queries which have a where clause on a field which is a non-unique non-clustered index, it is also a foreign key in table A. That foreign key is the primary key on table B and is the clustered index.

What I'm wondering is, will I get a performance gain if I add a join from table A to table B and have the where clause on the field which is the clustered index (as opposed to the non-clustered index without the extra join)?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

To really eke out that extra bit of performance, you'd be better off making sure that your non-unique, non-clustered index is a [covering index](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/covering_indexes_p1.aspx) (i.e., the index includes all of the columns needed to satisfy the query) for the query you're executing. You can take advantage of the concept of [included columns](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1078) introduced in SQL 2005 to help you do this.

Answer (score 1):

I've made some test. I have two tables - tableA (~3000 rows) and tableB (~200 rows). both of them has column id. TableA: ID - pk, TableB: ID - fk, non-clustered index.

Select from one table:

```
SELECT 
    a.ID
FROM
    dbo.TableA a
WHERE 
    a.ID IN (1,5,7,9,23,45,56,546,67,32,54,676)
```

---

-- EXECUTION PLAN:

```
|--Index Seek(OBJECT:([Database].[dbo].[TableA].[IX_TableA_ID] AS [a]), SEEK:([a].[ID]=(1) OR [a].[ID]=(5)) ORDERED FORWARD)
```

-- STATISTICS IO:

```
Table 'TableA'. Scan count 2, logical reads 4, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

---

Select using two tables (inner join)

```
SELECT 
    t.ID
FROM
    dbo.TableA a
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.TableB t  with(index(PK_TableBs)) ON t.ID = a.ID
WHERE 
    t.ID IN (1,5,7,9,23,45,56,546,67,32,54,676)
```

---

-- EXECUTION PLAN:

```
  |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([t].[ID]))
       |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([Database].[dbo].[TableB].[PK_TableB] AS [t]), SEEK:([t].[ID]=(1) OR [t].[ID]=(5)) ORDERED FORWARD)
       |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([Database].[dbo].[TableA].[IX_TableA_ID] AS [a]), SEEK:([a].[ID]=[Database].[dbo].[TableB].[ID] as [t].[ID]),  WHERE:([Database].[dbo].[TableA].[ID] as [a].[ID]>=(1) AND [Database].[dbo].[TableA].[ID] as [a].[ID]<=(5)) ORDERED FORWARD)
```

-- STATISTICS IO:

```
Table 'TableA'. Scan count 2, logical reads 4, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'TableB'. Scan count 2, logical reads 4, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

**Result:**

The second query cost is 67% (relative to the batch) against to the first query (33%).
Also, the second query requires more reads.

PS. This is dirty quick example, you shoud check your own.

Answer (score 0):

I would not think so, as adding another table would involve more reads. But you will have to test.

Answer (score 0):

No  as per Frank, this requires more page reads from Table B. You say you already have a NC Index on the Foreign Key on which the filtering is performed. You might also look at weighing up the pros and cons of clustering Table A by the FK (B's PK) - if you usually always fetch Table A by filtering on B, then this could reduce the number of pages fetched on A (but obviously, there may be other queries which could be impacted by this which could count against this)

Answer (score 0):

If you consider how the join is going to work - it's going to have to search for the FK column in table A in order to satisfy the join condition - which is the scan you seem to be trying to avoid. So I don't believe that there is any way that this could improve the performance.